# Undefined reference to SDL_Init ( CodeBlocks )

Tags: codeblocks, sdl-2

I wanted to teach myself SDL, but I encountered quite unpleasant problem in the very first try. I did some research and found out that I first need to make CodeBlocks know where library sits. First things first, I have 64-byte OS.

Just as I read, I put things in:

Project -> Linker settings ( direct links to .dll files, I chose x64 of course ), and "-lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2" in "other linker options". This one puzzles me a bit, but replacing 32 with 64 generates yet another error, so I kept it that way.

Project -> Search Directories:

```
-> Compiler: link to /include folder with header files
-> Linker: link to /lib folder with .dll files
```

I also made sure that these things are visible after clicking on project itself and choosing "build options".

Have I forgotten about something?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Undefined reference to SDL_Init() and every single function from SDL.

Answer (score 0):

You must have "compatible" versions of libraries and compiler - I mean architecture, 32 or 64 bits.
I see that you using MinGW 32-bits, so always use 32-bits SDL libraries.

It was about selecting version of SDL library. As for your main question, do you follow all steps about configuring SDL2 in CodeBlocks correctly?

1. Search Directories > Compiler > /include
2. Search Directories > Linker > /lib (**this folder should have .lib files, not .dlls**)
3. Linker settings > Other linker options: -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2

(graphical - In my opinion the best on internet - tutorial is [here](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/windows/codeblocks/index.php))

Do not set direct paths to DLL files. If you don't have `.lib` files, probably you downloaded wrong package from SDL site.